# Ruby: How do you access a subclass constant inside the parent class when defining a struct?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class Parent
  VALID_COLORS = ["blue"]
  
  MyStruct = Struct.new(:color) do
    def initialize(color:)
      raise "invalid color" unless self.class::VALID_COLORS.include?(color)
      super(color: color)
    end
  end
end

class Subclass < Parent
  VALID_COLORS = ["red"]

  def call
    MyStruct.new(color: "red")
  end
end

> Subclass.new.call
=> uninitialized constant Parent::MyStruct::VALID_COLORS
```

How can I access the correct `VALID_COLORS` constant in my struct initialization? Normally `self.class::CONSTANT` would allow you to access the subclass's constant while in the parent class, but it looks like `self.class` will bring up the struct instead while inside the struct. There are some workarounds I've thought of like 1) adding a new parameter to the struct to take in valid colors; or 2) setting `VALID_COLORS` as an instance variable instead of class variable. But I'm curious if there's a way to make my current implementation work as intended?

Comment: Don't do this. Have the struct accept valid colors as a parameter, and have `call` pass in the valid colors. The child should not have a circular dependency with its parent.

Comment: Also a struct *is* a class. There is no reason to expect `self.class` to be the parent class from within a nested class, that would make it impossible for the nested class to use `self.class`.

Comment: @runguacrun : You have now received several answers to your question. Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious if there's a way to make my current implementation work as intended?

Since you asked for it, let's give it a try.

First of all, your `Parent::MyStruct` already isn't working:

```
Parent::MyStruct.new(color: 'blue')
#=> NameError: uninitialized constant Parent::MyStruct::VALID_COLORS
```

That's because `VALID_COLORS` is defined in `Parent`, not in `Parent::MyStruct`. To dynamically reference the parent's namespace (in terms of [nesting](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Nesting)), Rails has [`module_parent`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-module_parent):

```
Parent::MyStruct.module_parent #=> Parent
```

Applied to your code: (I've also added `keyword_init: true` to make the struct take actual keyword arguments, see the docs for [`Struct.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Struct.html#new-method))

```
class Parent
  VALID_COLORS = ["blue"]

  MyStruct = Struct.new(:color, keyword_init: true) do
    def initialize(color:)
      raise "invalid color" unless self.class.module_parent::VALID_COLORS.include?(color)
      #                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives:

```
Parent::MyStruct.new(color: 'blue')
#=> #<struct Parent::MyStruct color="blue">
```

Now that we've fixed that one, let's try to create a struct through the subclass:

```
Subclass::MyStruct.new(color: 'red')
#=> RuntimeError: invalid color
```

This error occurs, because `Subclass::MyStruct` is in fact `Parent::MyStruct`:

```
Subclass::MyStruct #=> Parent::MyStruct
```

To fix this, `Subclass` needs its very own `MyStruct`.  We can solve it by creating a new class which inherits from `Parent::MyStruct`:

```
class Subclass < Parent
  VALID_COLORS = ["red"]

  MyStruct = Class.new(Parent::MyStruct)
end
```

The `Parent::` prefix is actually optional, but `MyStruct = Class.new(MyStruct)` looks too confusing.

The above gives:

```
struct = Subclass::MyStruct.new(color: 'red')
#=> #<struct Subclass::MyStruct color="red">

struct.is_a?(Subclass:MyStruct) #=> true
struct.is_a?(Parent::MyStruct)  #=> true
```

If you really want to use this approach, you could even move the dynamic class creation into `Parent` using the [`inherited`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Class.html#inherited-method) callback:

```
class Parent
  def self.inherited(subclass)
    subclass.const_set(:MyStruct, Class.new(self::MyStruct))
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `MyStruct`  constant is literally a reference to the object defined on `Parent`. When `Parent` is subclassed, the `MyStruct` object is not redefined, the reference is just copied. We can verify this with the following:

```
irb(main):014:0> Parent::MyStruct.object_id
=> 70326616692980
irb(main):015:0> Subclass::MyStruct.object_id
=> 70326616692980
```

To get around this, you could create a method that initializes the class object on the fly:

```rb
class Parent
  private

  def my_struct
    @my_struct ||= Struct.new(:color) do
      def initialize(color:)
        raise "invalid color" unless self.class::VALID_COLORS.include?(color)
        super(color: color)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you're willing to do a bit more work, making color it's own class instead of a struct would be a lot more robust:

```rb
class Color
  attr_accessor :color

  def initialize(color: color, valid_colors: Parent:: VALID_COLORS)
    raise "invalid color" unless valid_colors.include?(color)
    
    @color = color
  end
end

class Parent
  def self.color(color)
    Color.new(color: color, valid_colors: self.class::VALID_COLORS)
  end
end
```

Or you could try to investigate the caller to load the correct constant (I highly advise against this):

```rb
MyStruct = Struct.new(:color) do
  def initialize(color:)
    caller_path = caller_locations(1,1)[0].absolute_path
    valid_color_lib = {
      "parent.rb" => Parent::VALID_COLORS,
      "subclass.rb" => Subclass::VALID_COLORS
    }[caller_path]

    raise "invalid color" unless valid_color_lib.include?(color)
    super(color: color)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

A `VALID_COLORS`  is defined inside `Parent` and inside `Subclass` (which is irrelevant here).  The initializer of `Parent::MyStruct` also tries to access a constant of this name, but `MyStruct` does not have a `VALID_COLORS`.

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve, but depending on what you want, you can either do a

```
... unless Parent::VALID_COLORS.include?(color)
```

or a

```
... unless Subclass::VALID_COLORS.include?(color)
```

or provide another `VALID_COLORS` constant for `MyStruct`.